# Detect touch of an SKNode in a ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have an SKNode, a kind of joystick, into an SKView that is shown in a ViewController, like this:

```
class FeedVC: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    let joystick = Joystick()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let scene = SKScene(size: joystickView.frame.size)
        scene.backgroundColor = SKColor.white
        scene.addChild(joystick)
        joystick.position = CGPoint(x: scene.size.width / 2, y: scene.size.height / 2)
        joystickView.presentScene(scene)
    }
}
```

How can I detect only the touches on the joystick with the function `touchesMoved()`? If I override this method, it detects touches in all the view. 
I have only found answers where the class is a subclass of SKScene and not of UIViewController like mine.

Comment: Why don't you create a custom class `class myScene:SKScene { /* ... */ }` where you can override `touchesMoved` for that specific scene? What if you needed more than 1 scene, and you wanted different `touchesMoved` for each scene? Then you can keep a `touchesMoved` for the `ViewController` and another one for `SKScene`.  There is a reason people only have `touchesMoved` inside their subclass of `SKScene` ;)

Comment: Do you mean without creating the scene in the viewDidLoad() func?

Comment: I would not recommend this approach at all.  UIKit has enough graphic capabilities to handle a joystick overlay

Answer (score 0):

By using `touchesMoved()` you can detect the touch of your node like this:

```
override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.location(in: self)
        let node : SKNode = self.atPoint(location)

        if node.name == "joystick" {
            // Something, something, something...
        }
    }
}
```

By doing this you need to set the name for your node first.

Comment: It gives me the error: "Cannot invoke 'location' with an argument list of type '(in: FeedVC)'"

Answer (score 0):

```
class FeedVC: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    let joystick = Joystick()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let scene = MyScene(size: joystickView.frame.size)
        scene.backgroundColor = SKColor.white
        scene.addChild(joystick)
        joystick.position = CGPoint(x: scene.size.width / 2, y: scene.size.height / 2)
        joystickView.presentScene(scene)
    }
}
```

Your Custom SKScene class

```
class MyScene:SKScene {

    //... 

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        //This touchesMoved is NOT equal to the touchesMoved used for the ViewController since this ViewController is for ONLY the scene.
    }
}
```